# Making HSL pallet with selectable gradient problem

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

I am trying to make a color pallet in which the user can click on the gradient and it will show you the RGB and HSL values so far I have printed out all the Hue values and now what I want to do is make the appropriate display of Saturation and Luminesance/lightness values as can be seen here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Color_picker_tool

I have tried to use a double nested loop as a generator such as:

```
function * hslGen(hue){  
    for(let s = 0; s < 100; s++){
        for(let l = 100; l > 0; l--){
            yield `hsl(${hue}, ${s}%, ${l}%)`;}
    }
}
```

But the result looks the following https://codepen.io/superpauly/pen/XWMQboe?editors=1010 which confivuration should I have the loops to display a collor pallet like shown in the example above?

So I have got the generator and the rest of the code is as follow:

```
const canvasContext = canvRef.current.getContext("2d");
    for (let hue = 0; hue < 360; hue++) {
        // Generates Hue Spectrum
        canvasContext.fillStyle = "hsl(" + hue + ", 100%, 50%)";
        canvasContext.fillRect(5 * hue, 0, 5, 75);
    }
    
    canvRef.current.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        data = canvasContext.getImageData(e.layerX, e.layerY, 1, 1).data;
        color.rgb = `rgb( ${data[0]}, ${data[1]}, ${data[2]})`;
        color.h = rgbToHue(data);
        color.hsl = `hsl( ${color.h}, 100%, 50%)`;

        let pixel = 0;
        for (let m of hslGen(color.h)){
            canvasContext.fillStyle = m; //HSL Generator string
            canvasContext.fillRect(pixel+=1, 75, 1440, 500); // Here is where I try to make the gradient bu it fails.
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're changing the codepen, can you instead put a minimum reproducible example of what you have here?

Comment: What exactly is your expected result?

Comment: To get a color picker display that can be seen here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Color_picker_tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need track x and y coordinates for each pixel:

```
import React, {
    useEffect,
    useRef,
    useState
} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
import ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1";

console.clear();

function * hslGen(hue){

    for(let l = 100; l >= 0; l--)
    {
        for(let s = 0; s <= 100; s++)
        {
            yield `hsl(${hue}, ${s}%, ${l}%)`;
        }
    }
}

const RGBToHex = (r, g, b) => {
    r = r.toString(16);
    g = g.toString(16);
    b = b.toString(16);

    if (r.length == 1) r = "0" + r;
    if (g.length == 1) g = "0" + g;
    if (b.length == 1) b = "0" + b;

    return `#${r+g+b}`;
};

function rgbToHue(getImageData) {
    let rgbHue = {
        red: getImageData[0] / 255,
        green: getImageData[1] / 255,
        blue: getImageData[2] / 255
    };
    let maxValueKey = Object.keys(rgbHue).reduce((a, b) =>
        rgbHue[a] > rgbHue[b] ? a : b
    );
    let maxValue = Math.max(rgbHue["red"], rgbHue["green"], rgbHue["blue"]);
    let minValue = Math.min(rgbHue["red"], rgbHue["green"], rgbHue["blue"]);
    let hue = 0.0;
    switch (maxValueKey) {
        case "red":
            hue = (rgbHue["green"] - rgbHue["blue"]) / (maxValue - minValue);
            break;
        case "green":
            hue = 2.0 + (rgbHue["blue"] - rgbHue["red"]) / (maxValue - minValue);
            break;
        case "blue":
            hue = 4.0 + (rgbHue["red"] - rgbHue["green"]) / (maxValue - minValue);
            break;
    }
    hue = hue * 60.0;
    if (hue < 0.0) {
        hue = hue + 360.0;
    }
    console.log("Hue in Deg: " + hue);
    return hue;
}

const ColorPicker = () => {
    const canvRef = useRef();
    const color = { rgb: "", hsl: "",
                                h:0};
    let [col, setCol] = useState({});
    let data = 0;

    useEffect(() => {
        const canvasContext = canvRef.current.getContext("2d");
        for (let hue = 0; hue < 360; hue++) {
            canvasContext.fillStyle = "hsl(" + hue + ", 100%, 50%)";
            canvasContext.fillRect(5 * hue, 0, 5, 75);
        }
        
        canvRef.current.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            data = canvasContext.getImageData(e.layerX, e.layerY, 1, 1).data;
            color.rgb = `rgb( ${data[0]}, ${data[1]}, ${data[2]})`;
            color.h = rgbToHue(data);
            color.hsl = `hsl( ${color.h}, 100%, 50%)`;
            setCol({
                rgb: color.rgb,
                hsl: color.hsl
            });
            
            debugger;
            let x = 0,
                    y = 0,
                    pix = 3; //pixel size
            console.log("Start");
            for (let m of hslGen(color.h)){
                canvasContext.fillStyle = m;
                canvasContext.fillRect(100 + x, 175 + y, pix, pix); //Need to made this a 2d saturation, light graph
                console.log(m, x, y);
                x += pix;
                x = x % (pix * 101);
                if (!x)
                    y += pix;


            }
            console.log("End");
            
        });
    
        console.log(color);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <canvas
                ref={canvRef}
                height={window.innerHeight}
                width={window.innerWidth}
            ></canvas>
            <span>HSL: {col.hsl}</span>
            <span>RGB: {col.rgb}</span>
        </>
    );
};
```

ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById("colorCanvas"));

https://codepen.io/vanowm/pen/JjWgJOO

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using the generator you can do something like so:

```js
const scale = 4; // likely don't want the user to have to click on a single pixel so need some kind of scale factor

const hueInput = document.getElementById('hue');
const canvas = document.getElementById('color-picker');
canvas.width = 100 * scale;
canvas.height = 100 * scale;

canvas.style.width = canvas.width + 'px';
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + 'px';

const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function * hslGen(hue){  
    for(let s = 0; s < 100; s++){
        for(let l = 100; l > 0; l--){
            yield `hsl(${hue}, ${s}%, ${l}%)`;}
    }
}

function updateColorPicker() {
  const hue = hueInput.value;
  
  // need to keep track of both x and y as it's two dimensional
  let y = 0, x = 0;
  for (const m of hslGen(hue)) {
    context.fillStyle = m; //HSL Generator string
    context.fillRect(x * scale, y * scale, scale, scale);

   // iterator is doing saturation then lightness so we populate y first then x
   y++;
   if (y >= 100) {
     y = 0;
     x++;
   }
  }
}

hueInput.addEventListener('change', updateColorPicker);

updateColorPicker();
```

```html
<label> HUE <input type="number" id="hue" value="5"></label>
<br>
<canvas id="color-picker"></canvas>
```

Because the expected output is 2 dimensional you need both an `x` and `y` component.  Because of this, the generator in it's current form doesn't seem to make much sense.

A better approach would be to either remove the generator altogether, or make it fit the problem better. Here's an example without the generator :

```js
const scale = 4; // likely don't want the user to have to click on a single pixel so need some kind of scale factor

const hueInput = document.getElementById('hue');
const canvas = document.getElementById('color-picker');
canvas.width = 100 * scale;
canvas.height = 100 * scale;

canvas.style.width = canvas.width + 'px';
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + 'px';

const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function updateColorPicker() {
  const hue = hueInput.value;

  // need to keep track of both x and y as it's two dimensional
  for(let x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    for(let y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
      var m = `hsl(${hue}, ${x}%, ${100-y}%)`;
      context.fillStyle = m; //HSL Generator string
      context.fillRect(x * scale, y * scale, scale, scale);
    }
  }
}

hueInput.addEventListener('change', updateColorPicker);

updateColorPicker();
```

```html
<label> HUE <input type="number" id="hue" value="5"></label>
<br>
<canvas id="color-picker"></canvas>
```